# Height and Width C# Panel

Tags: c#, height, width, panel

I have a problem.
When I create my panel and I ask size (150;150) and I execute the program I dont have the good size.
So if ask the witdh and heigth I obtain (112;122)..

Do you have some idea for reason it?

Thank you

```
this.Zone_Impression.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.Zone_Impression.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
this.Zone_Impression.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
this.Zone_Impression.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
this.Zone_Impression.Name = "Zone_Impression";
this.Zone_Impression.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
this.Zone_Impression.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Give in the code that you tried .. both cs and aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `panel.AutoSize == true`?